# Export an array containing mysql results to another javascript file

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-modules

I making use of node.js + mysql in my app. I would like to export an array containing results/rows of an SQL select statement to another javascript file and display the values stored in the array.

**stats.js**

```
var phonenum='0718900000'
var sql='SELECT name,surname,age from Tbluser WHERE number=?;'
conn.query(sql,[phonenum],function(err,results){
                      if (err){
                        throw err;
                      };
                      /*if (results==0)
                      {
                        let dealersMessage="❌ User not found"
                      }*/
                      
              console.log(results)      
             var datastatagentStore=[];
             results.forEach(item =>{
                 module.exports=datastatagentStore.push({
                        name:item.name,
                        surname:item.surname,
                        age:item.age,
                      })
                    })
```

**app.js**

```
 var{datastatagentStore}=require('../functions/stats.js')

 console.log('User details '+datastatagentStore);
```

Comment: Generally what you'd export is the functionality to invoke the query, not the results of the query.  Is your goal really to invoke this operation only once, when the application starts, and keep the results as a static constant across the lifespan of the application?

Comment: Thank you for response @David. My goal is to execute the query and display the results to the user every time the user selects the 'view my details' button. I thought module.exports would be the solution to make my code cleaner, because  my code does contain numerous queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment above:

> My goal is to execute the query and display the results to the user every time the user selects the 'view my details' button.

Then you don't want to export the *results*, you want to export the *function which performs the query*.  That function would return [a `Promise` which resolves to] the results.

**If** `conn.query` returns a `Promise` then it might look something like this:

```
var getUserDetails = function (phonenum) {
  var sql='SELECT name,surname,age from Tbluser WHERE number=?;'
  return conn.query(sql, [phonenum], function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    };
    console.log(results)      
    var datastatagentStore = [];
    results.forEach(item => {
      datastatagentStore.push({
        name:item.name,
        surname:item.surname,
        age:item.age,
      })
    });
    return datastatagentStore;
  });
};

module.exports = getUserDetails;
```

Though I don't know if `conn.query` does return a `Promise`.  If it doesn't, you can manually create one:

```
var getUserDetails = function (phonenum) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var sql='SELECT name,surname,age from Tbluser WHERE number=?;'
    conn.query(sql, [phonenum], function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      };
      console.log(results)      
      var datastatagentStore = [];
      results.forEach(item => {
        datastatagentStore.push({
          name:item.name,
          surname:item.surname,
          age:item.age,
        })
      });
      resolve(datastatagentStore);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = getUserDetails;
```

Note the use of `resolve` and `reject` here to manually complete the `Promise`.  But however you structure it, the overall point is that your module export wouldn't be the results of having executed the query, it would be the function to execute the query.  And since executing the query is an asynchronous operation, that function should return a `Promise`.

Then you can use it like any other asynchronous operation:

```
var datastatagentStore = require('../functions/stats.js');

datastatagentStore('0718900000').then(function (details) {
  console.log('User details ', details);
});
```

Comment: It's working ;D thank you so much. I would like to display it to the user so I add it in a stringmessage. Is this the right approach?
      let dealersMessage = "User Stats:\n";
      datastatagentStore('0718900000').then(function(details){             
         dealersMessage+="name"+item.name+"surname:"+item.surname+"\n"+"age: "+item.age;
    })

Comment: @sima_thedeveloper: You can probably clean up the syntax a bit with [a template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead, but overall if you want to display the values in a string then that's reasonable.